# Self Hosting TinyMCE in Angular Project but Sill Getting Registration Nags

Tags: angular, tinymce

I have a working version of tinymce-angular and got it working easily using the npm install @tinymce-angular directive and adding a few config lines to my app.module.ts

Good so far, but this requires an API key (apparently its cloud hosted even though it pulls the resources down into my node_modules folder as part of the npm install.

So, I'm simply trying to convert this to "self hosted" in order to remove the registration message that appears every time the editor is loaded.

To do that, I've simply downloaded the tinymce.min.js and placed that file into my src directory under src/tiny/tinymce.min.js

I've also added the other tinymce assets under there as well (plugins, skins, themes).

Here is the code of my component where I'm hosting the editor:

```
<script src="@app/tiny/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinyEditor'
  });
 <!--TinyMCE-->
    <div fxLayout="row">
      <h4>Client Details</h4>
      <editor formControlName="details"
        id="tinyEditor"
        toolbar=""
        menubar="format"
        [init]="{plugins: ''}"
        [inline]="false"></editor>
    </div>
```

With this code, I get a working editor however, I also get the yellow alert bar indicating message below:

> This domain is not registered with TinyMCE Cloud. Start a free trial
>   to discover our premium cloud services and pro support.

If I add my API key to the editor tag, the nag goes away obviously. Any ideas what I'm missing for self hosting this?

Comment: I suspect it's not actually using your local copy, or the npm-installed version simply references the cloud version. Download the self-hosted version from www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/ and you'll not be prompted for API. You could debug the network calls within your browser on load if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. However, the file setup I indicate above IS the self hosted package at the URL you reference. There are actually 2, I've downloaded and tried both.

Comment: So, can self hosted version still use the npm installed assets under node_modules/@tinymce-angular? To allow me to use the <editor> tag in my component I registered that in app.module.ts using the import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';

Comment: Scott, I don't use npm for installation (or angular) so can't help you there. More magic than I like. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway pbuck. Hopefully someone has answer or example of self hosting tinymce in angular.

Answer (score 3):

Facing this challenge today I finally found an npm module that let's you self-host in an easy way: [ngx-tinymce](https://github.com/cipchk/ngx-tinymce).

First go to [TinyMCE's build customizer](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/custom-builds/), select your desired plugins and download. Unpack the zip file where you want to host TinyMCE.

Then install ngx-tinymce

```
npm install --save ngx-tinymce
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations:[...],
  imports: [
    NgxTinymceModule.forRoot({
      baseURL: '/path/to/hosted/tinymce/'
    }),
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...]
})
```

**some.component.html**

```
<tinymce [(ngModel)]="html"></tinymce>
```

Note: If you add configuration use an *ngIf to make sure you don't trigger ngOnChanges before tinymce is loaded. TinyMCE will work anyway, but it will throw an error in the debug console.

```
<tinymce *ngIf="config" [(ngModel)]="html" [config]="config"></tinymce>
```

Installation and first run did not reveal any api-key-message from TinyMCE. So it seems to work as expected.

Versions:

- Angular 7
- TinyMCE 4.9.1
- ngx-tinymce 2.1.1

Comment: After installing ngx-tinymce, I found @tinymce-angular and almost started switching to it. I read usage stats wrong, and didn't see an advantage to not using the official implementation. Your answer is the reason I'll stick for now with ngx-tinymce. Thanks for "documenting this feature"! :D