# Tinymce show me error and ask me to provide API key (paid)

Tags: javascript, plugins, cloud, tinymce

I use Tinymce on my website since years, and since few days, I can see the following message :

[image]

> A valid API key is required, starting 2024, to continue using TinyMCE.
> Please alert your admin to sign-up to get your free API key .

All my website is based on this plugin, so I don't understand why now they ask to pay (and free plan is only 1000 request per months !)

Did I misunderstand? How to continue using this very popular plugin without paying?

I see that my source code calls the cloud url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

What should I change?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Valeria from TinyMCE is here.

If you see a notification that an API key is required, it means that you’re using Tiny Cloud service. Most likely, you copied the sample code to add TinyMCE editor to your websites that used Tiny Cloud services.

It means that we host TinyMCE for you and take care of regular updates of it. Plus, you can access our Premium features like PowerPaste, Accessibility checkers, Advanced Templates, and many more if you need them via upgrading to one of our plans. Users who want to keep using our Tiny Cloud must now provide a valid API key.

If you use only open-source TinyMCE features, then consider moving TinyMCE to your cloud hosting. E.g., you can use TinyMCE via cdnjs or any other CDN of your choice. Please note, that the open-source TinyMCE is available under the MIT license.

In this case, you won't use our Tiny Cloud service and won't need to deal with editor loads. And if your project complies with the MIT license, you can keep using it for free.

We created a help document to provide more details: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/invalid-api-key/

Comment: Hey, thanks
How should I know which version I am using currently on my website? The file I load is tinymce.min.js so if I want the self hosted (as I don't use a lot the features, but more like a design textarea for my users) which CDN should I use to replace it and not need to update my website code?
Thanks

Comment: Thomas, you can use any CDN of your choice. There are several popular ones including CDNJS, UNPKG, and jsDelivr. You will stop seeing the notification in your editor once you switch from Tiny Cloud to another CDN.

Comment: Doesn't work with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/6.8.2/tinymce.min.js

Comment: Could you give us some more info on what is not working? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: You should choose "copy script tag" from the latest TinyMCE on  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tinymce.
Then place this script tag in an html page. Now, initialize TinyMCE using tinymce.init() and a textarea. You can use the javascript/html code in this basic fiddle example as a guide: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/

Comment: Valeria, we get this error when trialling the stock TinyMCE Blazor package on localhost. However we are not using the cloud service. Is there a way to opt out?

Comment: James, I am no longer with the company. Please get in touch with the support team for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are people choosing self-hosted solution (like in [Self Hosting TinyMCE in Angular Project but Sill Getting Registration Nags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993610/self-hosting-tinymce-in-angular-project-but-sill-getting-registration-nags?rq=2)) which I'm also going to suggest.

You migth end-up using old version of the script, which can also lead to different problems, but there is a free alternative if you are keen to deal with compability issues.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer,
Is self hosted simply to upload a .js file on my server and call it, like jquery or bootstrap ?

Comment: Exactly. You just need to change "src" attribute of your script tag to the link to your hosted file. The harder part would be finding a suitable version, which doesn't ask for api-key

Comment: I made my site years ago (Like 3-4 years) and I use few features, it was just to get a design text area I didn't thought they could make it paid, it's quite unfair as I don't have someone to update my code or find the good version
Self hosted can ask api key too?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue. This how i solved this problem in few clicks:

1. Go to their official website. Link: https://www.tiny.cloud/pricing/
2. Choose a plan. (you can go with free plan also)
3. Sign up
4. After successfully logging in, click on **Get your API KEY**.
5. Then copy that api key and put in your code, as shown on their website.